# Blueimp fileupload opens file picker when whitespace is clicked.

Tags: javascript, html, css, file-upload, blueimp

Working on a pre-existing project, I found that the fileupload input triggers when whitespace after the input element is clicked, extending through several tags above it, and ending, in my page, only when it gets to a pair of `<li>` which contain form elements. (If there is one or fewer of these list items, the problem persists to the bottom of the page.)

I have a pair of JSFiddles with the minimal examples I could construct. I'm totally baffled what's going on here.

Example with one list item, behavior continues to bottom of window: https://jsfiddle.net/e980gzry/

Example with two list items, behavior stops above the first list item: https://jsfiddle.net/o76qd639/5/

Has anyone run into this situation before, and how could I go about addressing it?

Comment: try removing `width:100%;` from the input element. That makes the text "Add files..." the only click target.

Comment: No good; the whole box containing 'Add files' needs to be selectable.

Comment: That does give me an idea, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind using javascript to trigger the file browser, you can do something like this using jquery:

```
$(function () {
  // whenever .fileinput-button is clicked, trigger a click on the input element
  $(".fileinput-button").on('click', function (e) {
    $("#fileupload").click();
  });
});
```

But if you use this directly you will need to move the `input` outside of `.fileinput-button` as well:

```
<div class='box-content'>
  <span class='fileinput-button' style='color: #008fd2; border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e2e5'>
      <i class='fa fa-upload'>
        <span>
          <i class="fa fa-fa-upload"></i> Add files...
        </span>
      </i>
  </span>
  <input id='fileupload' multiple='' name='files[]' type='file'>
</div>
```

And simplify the css, removing the `.fileinput-button input` definition:

```
.fileinput-button {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#fileupload {
  display: none;
}
```

[See complete jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e980gzry/2/), tested in chrome and firefox.

By the way, the problem you're seeing is that browsers don't like giving complete css control over input elements. So this is just a workaround for that.